# What do we mean by the phrase 'conventions of standard written English'

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, subcontinental-english, north-american-english

A question came and it had one of its options: correct according to conventions of standard English.
I don't remember the question but the question was from a grammar section.

I do not have an idea that there are actually some conventions in English language and would be grateful if anyone can tell me what the different conventions in the English Language are.

Comment: These are the conventions that you will find discussed in any comprehensive style guide.

Comment: Answering this question is the purpose of *this entire site.*

Comment: One of the conventions is to capitalize names of languages: Tagalog, Spanish, English, Hindi, etc. I notice that many do not so I assume they are using IM (instant messaging) style....

Comment: @phoog Most style guides recommend rather than discuss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to understand this sentence is to first think about the word "convention"; what is a convention?

According to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/convention), a convention is *a rule, method or practice established by usage*.

In other words, a convention is the generally accepted way of doing something.

Therefore, the sentence *correct according to conventions of standard English* means that the option was correct because it follows the accepted rules (and possible quirks) of standard (normal) English.

Comment: I added the link to your citation

Comment: Thank you for that, @ab2. I probably should have added a link to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Since the first answer has comprehensively answered part of your question, I'll answer the other part which asks about some conventions used in English language.

- Making a text italic, bold or underlining it to make emphasis is a convention.
- Increasing the font size (I mean really big) of the first letter for the first paragraph in an article is a convention.

Conventions are not really strict rules but  "habits" that are popular